# Ajax retrieve json data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am trying to retrieve json data using jquery ajax.

```
alert(data.EntryList.Entry.FirstName) //This returns undefined
```

I am trying to get the value of first name, last name etc.

Here is the code looks like

```
$.ajax({
        url: "",
        context: document.body,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(data) {


            console.log(data);

            alert(data.EntryList.Entry.FirstName)

        }


}); //Ajax End​
```

Console log screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what others have said you could also use `$.map()`   or   `$.each()` functions that JQuery provides to iterate over arrays.

```
var entries = data.EntryList.Entry;
$.each(entries, function(index,entry) {
  console.log(entry.FirstName);
});
```

or

```
var entries = data.EntryList.Entry;
$.map(entries, function(entry,index) {
  console.log(entry.FirstName);
});
```

And also `data.EntryList[i].Entry.FirstName` is an `object` . So `alert` may not be doing what you intend it to do. You should alert `data.EntryList[i].Entry.FirstName.value`

Comment: Index is the index of the element entry in the array entries

Answer (score 6):

try `alert(data.EntryList.Entry[0].FirstName)`  as EntryList.Entry is an array

Answer (score 3):

`data.EntryList.Entry` is an array.

```
var entries = data.EntryList.Entry;
for (var i = 0, l = entries.length; i < l; i++) {
  console.log(entries[i].FirstName.value);
  console.log(entries[i].LastName.value);
}
```